# What are the best practices of custom application Wordpress development?

Tags: wordpress, model-view-controller

I have a mid size project that I need to implement on Wordpress. I am fimiliar with MVC but don't know if I can use it in conjunction with Wordpress?

I intent to use wordpress loaded images, Menus and theme only from the wordpress every thing else particularly pages ( that are going to be linked with menus) isolated from wordpress. So whenever a page is requested WP controller delagates control to my controller. This is getting me headache !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merely use everything in conjunction with Wordpress, however, if you tightly couple with Wordpress you can't:

- Unit-Test your code.
- Integration-Test you code (in a practically successful way).
- Manage and automate staging of your code.

While you speak about MVC I assume you use it as a term for the high-level-design of a software. As long as you're able to decouple your project from Wordpress itself, the answer is yes.

If you're not able to do so, the answer is no. Wordpress itself does not offer anything that you could re-use easily to bring in MVC, it's own design is something totally different.

However as Wordpress is a software with a level of legacy introduced complexity, you need to think twice if it is actually worth to completely de-couple from Wordpress or if it's not just the technical debt it comes with that you need to legacy-align your code as well.

I highly suggest to use a decentralized version control system like git to create whatever you do. You can find a github mirror of Wordpress here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress

I'd say for small to mid-size projects this is the tool of choice. Keep design decisions low, as you're integrating with an existing platform so that you can't do anything greenfield anyway.

Comment: I intent to use wordpress loaded images, Menus and theme only from the wordpress every thing else particularly pages ( that are going to be linked with menus) isolated from wordpress. So whenever a page is requested WP controller delagates control to my controller. This is getting me headache !!!

Comment: Yes, I can imagine that this is giving much of a headache because this is a "good" example what can be *very awful* to do with Wordpress. I can highly not suggest you to do that unless you are firm with how Wordpress works and some good programming skills. You need to find the right place in there that is fitting best for your needs (WP_Query, Data access layer, ...). This highly depends on what you do, so I suggest get some Wordpress consulting on your problem.